# How to use in std::variant a type that uses the same std::variant?

Tags: c++11

I need a type to store variables of various types, including vectors and maps with this type, how can I do this in C++17?

The example below shows what I need to get, but it does not work.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<class V>
using var_type_base = std::variant<bool, int, double, std::string, std::vector<V>, std::map<std::string, V>>;
using var_type = var_type_base<var_type_base>;


int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0.;
    std::string s = "s";
    std::vector<int> v{0};
    std::map<std::string, int> mi;
    std::map<std::string, double> md;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> ms;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> mvi;
    std::map<std::string, var_type> m{
    {"i", i},
    {"d", d},
    {"s", s},
    {"vi", vi},
    {"mi", mi},
    {"md", md},
    {"ms", ms},
    {"mvi", mvi}};
    var_type v = m;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `using var_type = var_type_base<var_type_base<int>>;`?

Comment: @j6t No, I've edited the example to more accurately illustrate what is required.

Answer (score 2):

wrapping it in a struct seems to work in c++17

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
std::variant<bool, int, double, std::string, std::vector<foo>, std::map<std::string, foo>> bar;
template<class A>
foo(A x): bar(x) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, foo> m;
    m.emplace("a",1);
    foo v = m;
    return 0;
}
```

The caveat is that it can only store `map<string,foo>`, but not `map<string,int>` ... unless you also define maps and vectors of them in the variant ie:

```
variant<...... , map<string,int>> bar;
```